# Samba share is read-only after upgrading to Mac OS "BigSur"

Tags: macos, readonly, samba

Not sure if this is ok, but I just wanted to document for others how to work around this issue.  After upgrading to MacOS Big Sur, I was no longer able to write files to a sambashare hosted on a local network Linux machine.  Turns out that I was connecting as a "guest".  What finally worked for me was to make the connection [Cmd+K] and enter the user along with the ip address on my LAN:

[image]

smb.conf for the share looks like this:

```
[devshare]
   comment = Local Cover Images for BIS
   path = /home/steve/dev/share
   Valid users = steve
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
```

After clicking [Connect] with a *valid user* in the address, I was able to both read and write to my [devshare].

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't pose it in the form of a question, but the answer is there.  Be sure to see that the user is listed as a Valid user in the smb.conf (located in /etc/samba/ on my linux machine).

Comment: Hey Steve can you give an example of the portion that is needed in the smb.conf?

Comment: @Depechie - It's up there in the question.  Just list all the users you want to be "allowed"  after the keywords "Valid user ="  -- they may need to be valid userids on your linux box too.  Mine are.  Replace [devshare] with whatever your samba share point is.